# extra padding in gmail

Tags: html, css, gmail, html-email

I am making HTML emailer. When I view the template in gmail, it puts extra padding around the image.

I have used:

```
border-spacing:0;
display:block;
```

But it's not working.

**HTML**

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; margin: 0 auto; border-spacing:0px;  margin-left: 15px;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="110">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" height="100" valign="top" width="110">
                                <p style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                                    <a class="modimg" style="text-decoration: none!important;" href="#">
                                        <img style="display: block; border: 3px solid #ffcbbc; outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" alt="" src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455949782.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110">
                                    </a>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="h2" style="font-weight: bold;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 0px;color:#ffffff;">
                <p style="padding: 0; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 110px; text-align: center;font-size: 10px;">
                    <span class="wrap_textbox">Mr. R. Chandrasekhar</span>
                </p>
                <p style="padding:0; margin:0 auto; max-width:110px;text-align: center !important; font-size: 8px;">
                    <span class="wrap_textbox">President at NASSCOM</span>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank You.

Comment: Could you show us a visual example / your code so far?

Comment: good idea roberrrt

Comment: code please, otherwise we will be guessing at what the cause of the issue is: [mcve]

Comment: i have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `padding:0` , `margin:0`. according to your need where you want to put them.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce your issue above, however I noticed a few things missing that might solve the problem.

Try this (starts on line 6 of your example above).

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="110">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" height="100" valign="top" width="110">
                <a class="modimg" style="text-decoration: none!important;" href="#">
                    <img style="display: block; border: 3px solid #ffcbbc; outline: none; text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 1;" alt="" src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455949782.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110">
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what i want to do is.. when i see HTML email in gmail , then gmail leaves some extra padding around image.